# Plugin to play video content from my blog/website.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, apache-flex, silverlight, plugins

I wish to play **video content** (in a container) **from my website/ blog** when the page is loaded. **This would be similar to that of YouTube, Dailymotion etc...**

I would like to have the actual URL in the container which would then play the video at the location of the URL. The basic idea is to hide the actual URL from the user and make the person to view the video from the current page.

Could someone suggest some feasible ideas to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+flv+player) turned up:

[JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)

There are other FLV players out there (this one also claims to handle MP4), and that's only one possible format.  Any more detailed answer would require answering what format you want to serve up, whether you want streaming capabilities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen a lot of sites do ([NBC Video Player](http://www.nbc.com/The_Office/video/episodes/#apl=true) for example), is the following:

- Create a VideoPlayer.swf which has the video player functionality.
- Pass in a cryptic key to the VideoPlayer.swf via [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and `flashParams`
- VideoPlayer.swf sends that key to the server.
- Server sends back video data somehow to VideoPlayer.swf and it does its thing.

If you go to [this NBC Office episode](http://www.nbc.com/The_Office/video/episodes/#vid=1200746) at `http://www.nbc.com/The_Office/video/episodes/#vid=1200746`, and look at the source, you won't find that `1200746` value anywhere, so maybe it's not in `flashParams`.  Looks like they store that in an [`init.xml`](http://www.nbc.com/The_Office/video/episodes/init.xml?) file via `<videoID> 1200746</videoID>`, and they probably use [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) to map that `#vid=1200746` anchor to that xml file in VideoPlayer.swf, send it to their secure server, and return the video and ads they want.

Hope that helps,
Lance